# LinkedHashMap program is giving is not generic; it cannot be parameterized error

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashmap

I have made a Student class and it in not getting initialized with LinkedHashMap. Giving compile time error :

```
The type LinkedHashMap is not generic; 
it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Student, Integer>.
```

CODE :

StudentLinkedMap :

```
 public class LinkedHashMap {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Map <Student,Integer> students = new  LinkedHashMap<Student,Integer>();

Student s1 = new Student(1,2,"Dhwani","Pandya");
Student s2 = new Student(2,2,"Priyam ","Parekh");
Student s3 = new Student (3,2,"Sucheta","Shrivastava");
Student s4 = new Student(3,6,"Nirali","Rokadia");
Student s5 = new Student(2,6,"Kajari","Agrawal");

students.put(s1,2);
students.put(s2,4);
students.put(s3,6);
students.put(s4,5);
students.put(s5,7);

for(Map.Entry lhs:students.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(lhs.getKey()+ "  "+ lhs.getValue());
}

}

}
```

Student Class:

```
  public class Student {

private int rollno;
private  String firstname;
private  String lastname;
private  int std;

 public Student(int rollno, int std,String firstname, String lastname){

    this.firstname=firstname;
    this.lastname=lastname;
    this.rollno=rollno;
    this.std=std;

    }

@Override
public String toString(){
    return ("\troll no="+ this.rollno + "\tstandard="+ 
 this.std+"\tfirstname="+this.firstname+"\tlastname="+this.lastname);
 }


 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have named **your** class `LinkedHashMap` so the name shadows `java.util.LinkedHashMap`. You can either change the name of your class, **or** use the fully qualified class name.

```
Map<Student,Integer> students = new java.util.LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Comment: after making the changes  gives the error - LinkedHashMap cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: But i am getting the same 6  outputs -    roll no=2 standard=6 firstname=Kajari lastname=Agrawal  2
 roll no=2 standard=6 firstname=Kajari lastname=Agrawal  4
 roll no=2 standard=6 firstname=Kajari lastname=Agrawal  6
 roll no=2 standard=6 firstname=Kajari lastname=Agrawal  5
 roll no=2 standard=6 firstname=Kajari lastname=Agrawal  7

Comment: That is a runtime error, seems like your compiler error is fixed. You are using `Student` as a key to the `Map`, but you aren't overriding `hashCode`... do so (and don't forget to [override `equals`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/2970947) as well).

Comment: . why is overriding hashcode and equals so important

Comment: Because a `Map` (or `Set`) doesn't allow duplicate keys, so the first thing it does is get the hash of instances to determine where to store it. Once it has that it compares with any values already there, if they're equal it stores the new instance and evicts the old one.

Comment: I am unable to create equals method. can you help me define it. i created the hashcode method please check if that is correct. I posted in the answer section.